# Closed in X $\implies$ Closed in Y?

Tags: general-topology

Let Y be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If X is a closed subset of Y, disjoint from the boundary of Y, is it true that X is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? How do I show this?

Edit: Let X be contained in a closed set B of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is contained in Y and which is disjoint from the boundary of Y. Then X is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: how do I accept if people answer via comments or if the comments were more helpful than the answers?

Comment: There is a checkbox to the left of the answers.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but how about $n=1$, $Y=(0,1)$, and $X=[1/2,1)$? You might ask the same question, but demand that  the boundary of $Y$ be disjoint from the boundary of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

If a set $A$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then there is a sequence $x_n\in A$ converging to $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$. (Why?)

Do you see where to go from there?